# Equivalence between polygon definitions.

Tags: geometry, definition, polygons

I generaly find the definition of polygon as a "polygonal chain", but I barely find another definition that defines a convex polygon as the intersection of a finite number of half-planes and defines polygon as the union of a finite number of convex polygons.

The first one is used everywhere but I find it vague, like with proofs of convexity or to tell if a point is in a polygon. The second one explains this, but doesnt talk at all about the vertices or edges, and when I find this definition it is just assumed that those exists.

Does anyone has any reference of a robust definition?

Comment: How about "compact region in the plane whose boundary is a finite union of line segments"?

Comment: If we're talking about synthetic geometry, check Hilbert's Foundations of Geometry. However he doesn't prove the main theorem about polygons. I asked about it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904233/interior-and-exterior-of-a-polygon-in-hilbert-axioms

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sounds more like a topological definition than a geometric one. With that definition I think I would have problems when talking about non-topological properties like distance.

Comment: Welcome back, Santiago. How about if I replace "plane" with "Euclidean plane"?

Comment: Are you still here, Santiago?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with that definition.
I think the problem is that I was not specific enough. 
Given that my starting point is geoemtry in the euclidean plane, I was trying to justify claims of the above without all the background about topology. Something along the lines of what Kulisty was saying.